# How to show more languages in iTunes Store App description?

Tags: ios, itunes, itunes-store

How can my app show more then one language in the iTunes AppStore? My application is translated in 5 languages , but when I upload it to iTunesConnect it doesn't show me the other languages in iTunes, only English. I attached a pic of an app where it is shown that it supports more languages:
http://msf-invest.com/images/pic1.png

So how can I do the same - my app to shows other languages (for ex. English, Russian , German). I mean all the languages in which my app is translated into.

Answer (score 1):

If you have translated the application, and your project settings are set to support several localization (see screenshot from one of my projects), then it should show. Please make sure the project is localized.

[image: A localized project]

Comment: So thank you for your answer, but in my project all localization files are defined like yours at your screenshot. A saw that in the TARGET section under Info tab there is a key Localizations and I see only English there. If I add all my rest languages there what will happen?

Comment: I guess you mean `CFBundleLocalizations`, I think that might actually do the trick. I don't have it in my app, however I just redid my targets which could be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

How do you manage translations ? If you are using the NSLocalizedString macro, you need a Localized.strings file for each language. 
Just add the translation folders (containing each Localized.strings file) to your project : en.lproj, fr.lproj, ... iTunes will automatically recognize those.